# Eclipse launchers - want to appear in Debug only

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

In Eclipse i created some launchers, after run it, it appearing in run and debug launchers both lists, but few launchers i don't want to appear in run(I always like to run them in debug mode only.).

Do you have any idea to do that way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do that. However, when you run or debug an application, it will appear in the history that you see in the drop down next to the run or debug button in the toolbar. This is a list of recently launched applications (whether it is run or debugged). However, a list of favorites appears here, too, if you've set the appropriate option ("Debug" or "Run") in the launch configuration **Common** tab. The favorites should stay in the chosen list, whilst the recently launched list will change as you launch applications. I don't know if this helps.